# Heroku + Haml Problems

Tags: permissions, heroku, haml

I am having issues with Heroku and Haml, I am able to run my app on localhost no problems, all test pass to, however when I go to run it on Heroku I get the following error:

`We're sorry, but something went wrong.`

`We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.`

I read another post on Stackoeverflow that basically said to add a .gems file and add:

`haml --version '>= 2.2.0'`

I did that and I'm still having the same problem, so I'm wondering what I am doing wrong.

**Update**: I fixed that problem had to do with cache - and Heroku being read-only however now the theme I've selected via web-app does not load up on the Heroku page it shows up on local host however correctly. I looked at the log file for Heroku and it doesn't show any errors, so is it another permission issue?

Here is the log file - https://gist.github.com/1173667

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your stylesheets are not included as part of the layout.

Assuming your stylesheet is available as `public/stylesheets/styles.css`, try adding the following line inside the head tag in `application.html.haml`

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'styles.css'
```

That should resolve the theming issue. If not, post the code in application.html.haml

**UPDATE:**

From the logs, looks like you have two layouts: layouts/sign and layout/application. If they are there for a reason, you need to address that.

Else, change your home controller to render the new layout:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  layout "sign"
end
```

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't seem to resolve the issue, here is the application.html.haml file - https://gist.github.com/1174109

Comment: updated my answer. looks like you have two layouts and only one has the styles.

Comment: Thanks alot that worked! I have two because I was using a different style/layout for the sign in page vs the main homepage.